# What is the electric field intensity inside a conducting sphere when charges are asymetrically distributed over the surface?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors

While considering the Gauss law for a conducting sphere with a uniform charge distribution on its surface, it can be shown that the electric filed inside the conducting sphere is zero.

But, what would happen if charges are asymmetrically distributed on its surface? What would be the electric field inside the conducting sphere in this case?

Comment: The charges would distribute on the surface in such a way that the field vanishes exactly everywhere in the inside

Comment: Suppose you bring a positive charge close to the conductor (say, which had uniformly distributed negative charges on its surface before), but not touching it. So what will happen to the electric filed inside now?

Comment: The argument for steady-state fields in a conductor being zero does not depend on symmetry, uniform change distributions or Gauss' law. It really only depends on the definition of a conductor (charge moves easily) and the idea that the pool of available changes is effectively infinite (true until charge densities reach many Coulombs per molar volume).

Comment: @dmckee : This appears to be an answer-in-comment.

Comment: Please can you give an example of what you mean? Why do you think the result will be different if charge is not distributed symmetrically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electric Field Inside a Conductor at Different Charge Densities](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/246568/)

Comment: well, I am just asking generally since I can,t provide a mathematical approach. I am a Biologist. But if you search for Prof. Walter Lewin's MIT lectures on you tube, you will hear that he is mentioning this briefly and clearly says that the electric filed inside the conductor WOULD NOT BE ZERO, if charge distribution is not uniform.

Comment: I suspect—without having watched the video—that you have failed to notice a subjunctive mood in the presentation. The claim is that given (a) a conductor (b) of spherical shape that is (c) isolated from other charges, **then** to have zero field in the interior requires a uniform charge distribution on the surface. Which is perfectly true, but but not as informative or useful as a discussion of the process by which zero steady-state fields establish themselves in the first place. In any case, break any of those conditions, and the conclusion changes.